# Android Lombok IntelliJ integration

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm trying to include lombok in my android project, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.
The project is built with maven. I've added the lombok dependency and compiling the project with maven succeeds.

In IntelliJ I've installed the lombok plugin which also works - I see the generated getters/setters.

Hovewer, when I try to make the project in IntelliJ, the build fails:

> > error: cannot find symbol method setName(String)

In a standard Java environment, adding lombok to the classpath would be sufficient for the project to compile. What in the android environment is causing the compilation to fail?

EDIT: I've created an issue on the IntelliJ Bugtracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94749

Comment: Did you add the dependency to the module in IDEA? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: The dependency is added automatically because of the maven integration. All maven dependencies end up in the classpath of the IntelliJ module.

Comment: Could it have to do with the ConstructorProperties annotation that is generated for all generated constructors, including those generated by @Data? To test this you can add @RequiredArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties=true) and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: See also http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=420 and http://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html

Comment: I've added the suggested annotation and unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94749. It looks like they fixed it. Haven't tried it out yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a bug and they fixed it in IntelliJ **IDEA 12.1**:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94749

Answer (score 1):

have your tried to Enable annotation processing ?

go under Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors. and make sure 'Enable annotation processing' is enabled.